# extjs 4 tree store RESTful

Tags: rest, tree, extjs4, store

i m working with Extjs 4 Tree with Rails 3 as backend & was wondering is there any REST support as for TreeStore as we have it for data store? I tried a lot of googling but could nt find any full fledged tutorial.. 
I want to dynamically add nodes to tree & tree store should be synchronized so that next time tree loads newly created node also exists..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is handled by your chosen proxy. Simply set the `Ext.data.TreeStore`'s proxy to `type: rest`.

Please see the following for reference:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-proxy

and

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest

Comment: thnx for quick reply...i tried setting proxy to rest n then calling treestore.sync() which in turn calls rest methods,but im not able to dynamically add children to node.. can u plzz suggest me any ref links for example??